# Turbolinks in Rails 5 Break Bootstrap Select Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, turbolinks

I have a Rails 5 app running on Heroku using Bootstrap 3.

I have this form:

```
.panel-body
  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label :kind, 'Swim, Bike or Run?'
     = f.select :kind, Workout.kinds.keys.to_a.map { |s| [s.humanize, s] }, {}, class: 'select'
```

**Problem:** *Without* Turbolinks it renders a nice 'Select' form. *With* Turbolinks it renders a normal browser dropdown. I would like to render the nice 'Select' class form. I could disable Turbolinks, but I need it elsewhere in the app.

I need Turbolinks enabled because I'm injecting data into the form from a .coffee file.

View:

```
.panel-footer.panel-footer-condensed
  .heading-elements
    span.heading-text
      strong
        a(
          data-type="useTemplate"
          data-kind=template.kind
          data-distance=template.distance
          data-duration=template.duration
          data-notes=template.notes
         )
         | Use Template
```

Coffee file:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('a[data-type="useTemplate"]').click (e) ->
    $('#workout_kind').val(e.target.dataset.kind)
    $('#workout_distance').val(e.target.dataset.distance)
    $('#workout_duration').val(e.target.dataset.duration)
    $('#workout_notes').val(e.target.dataset.notes)
```

Question: How can I get my dropdown to keep the styling of the 'Select' class?

If there is another easier solution, I'm also eager to hear. I have tried using .on 'page:load' and .on 'document:load' but it does not inject the values into the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks was messing with a whole bunch of things in the app so I decided to simple remove Turbolinks and change my coffee file to this instead:

```
$ ->
  $('a[data-type="useTemplate"]').click (e) ->
    $('#workout_kind').val(e.target.dataset.kind)
    $('#workout_distance').val(e.target.dataset.distance)
    $('#workout_duration').val(e.target.dataset.duration)
    $('#workout_notes').val(e.target.dataset.notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this,

**css_property_name1|2** means css properties name like height,width,line-heigth,padding,etc., styles that can be applied to element

```
    $(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
      $('.select').css
        'css_property_name1': 'property1value'
        'css_property_name2': 'property2value'
```